# Where to change password when browsing webdav shares with dolphin?

Tags: kde, webdav

I am accessing webdav shares with Dolphin. I had saved the password for entering these shares. After changing the password in Firefox, Dolphin can no longer access the shares (as it does not have saved the correct password). However, it does not promt me for the new credentials. Where is this password stored and how can I change it?

I am using Kubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open kwalletmanager. (Alt + F2 and type wallet). There you can manually edit the passwords. The fact that you are not prompted to enter new credentials is most probably a bug.

Comment: What to do If kwallet is disabled (but problem described in question exists)?

Comment: @diraria I do not know where passwords are stored when kwallet is disabled.